# Create a jQuery variable that holds multiple variables

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clean up my code and was curious if it's possible to create a variable that contains other variables.

Pretty much I'm trying to turn this...

```
// variables are elements on a page
var1.show();
var2.show();
var3.show();
var4.hide();
var5.hide();
```

Into this...

```
var showViewVariables = (var1, var2, var3);
var hideViewVariables = (var4, var5);

showViewVariables.show();
hideViewVariables.hide();
```

Not sure if this fails to work due to my syntax or if its even capable.

I've found some answers where multiple selectors are placed in a variable and called together but haven't found much of anything with variables inside one variable.

Comment: what is var1, var2? are they string selectors or jquery objects?

Comment: They are selectors... so a div on the page that I'm trying to hide or show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements.

*Example*

```
var var1 = $('#one');
var var2 = $('#two');

//Create variable from another variables
var var3 = var1.add(var2);

var3.show();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0a4n2w9f/)

Comment: change your fiddle to use a different jQuery version rather than compat and it will work

Comment: Im guessing this is the closest that we can get to what the OP wnats